# Doctrine 2 unable to find Proxy directory (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, orm, doctrine, doctrine-orm

Following a Doctrine / CodeIgniter [tutorial](http://www.joelverhagen.com/blog/2011/05/setting-up-codeigniter-2-with-doctrine-2-the-right-way/)

Everything is good up until the very end when I try to insert data through my controller

```
    $user = new Entities\User;
    $user->setFirstName('Joel');

    $this->doctrine->em->persist($user);
```

I get:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\Proxy\ProxyException' with message 'You must configure a proxy directory. See docs for details' in C:\wamp\www\ci\application\libraries\Doctrine\ORM\Proxy\ProxyException.php on line 33
( ! ) Doctrine\ORM\Proxy\ProxyException: You must configure a proxy directory. See docs for details in C:\wamp\www\ci\application\libraries\Doctrine\ORM\Proxy\ProxyException.php on line 33
```

This might be due to a difference in the tutorial version of Doctrine vs. the current version [as noted here](http://www.joelverhagen.com/blog/2011/05/setting-up-codeigniter-2-with-doctrine-2-the-right-way/#comment-459214423), but the tutorial version is no longer supported by Doctrine and I'm not sure what to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you set the proxy directory by doing somewhere :

```
// set up proxy configuration
$config->setProxyDir(APPPATH.'models/Proxies');
$config->setProxyNamespace('Proxies');
```

You have a problem with the setting of the proxy dir.
Check that the proxy directory is well defined and that the directory exists.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Found the problem, you pointed me in the right direction.  Because I don't have APC caching I had to comment out those lines, but because the creator didn't use brackets around if/else it took my proxy declarations as an ELSE block.  Stupid shorthand, thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like permission trouble:

To fix, i did

> sudo chown -R www-data:www-data .